# Averaging Scores Simplification

Tags: java

I wrote a program which reads data from a file that contains the name of a student and an indefinite number of scores for each student, I have to calculate the average scores, but I can only seem to make the program work for an specific number of scores. How could I make it so it calculates the average of any number of scores. By the way the program is written in Java.

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package hw1;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class HW1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    try
    {
    File file = new File("/Users/admin/Desktop/studentScores.in");  //reads form file

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file); //scans the file

    while(scan.hasNextInt()) //while the scanner identifies integers
    {
         String name = scan.next();

         String grade1 = scan.next();

         String grade2 = scan.next();

         String grade3 = scan.next(); 

         String grade4 = scan.next(); 

         String grade5 = scan.next(); 

         String grade6 = scan.next(); 

         String grade7 = scan.next(); 

         String grade8 = scan.next(); 

         String grade9 = scan.next(); 

         String grade10 = scan.next(); 

         int average = (Integer.parseInt(grade1) + Integer.parseInt(grade2) + Integer.parseInt(grade3) + Integer.parseInt(grade4) + Integer.parseInt(grade5) + Integer.parseInt(grade6) +Integer.parseInt(grade7) + Integer.parseInt(grade8) +              Integer.parseInt(grade9) + Integer.parseInt(grade10)) / 10;
         //decalre avergae variable and calculate it
         System.out.println("Name:" + name + " Average:" + average); // print the name of the        student and their average
    }
    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does the number of scores vary per student, or is it constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final File file = new File("/Users/admin/Desktop/studentScores.in");  // reads from file

    try {
        final Scanner  scan = new Scanner(file); // scans the file


        while (scan.hasNext()) { // while the scanner identifies student names
            final String name = scan.next();

            int nbGrades = 0;
            int totalGrades = 0;

            while (scan.hasNextInt()) { //while the scanner identifies grades
                int grade = scan.nextInt();

                nbGrades++;
                totalGrades += grade;
            }

            // declare average variable and calculate it
            final BigDecimal average = new BigDecimal(totalGrades).divide(new BigDecimal(nbGrades));

            System.out.println("Name:" + name + " Average:" + average);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The idea is to use two loops:

- one to get the student names
- one to get the grades.

In the second loop, you count the number of grades found by increasing `nbGrades`, and you increase the total of the grades by the grade found.

For the average, it uses a `BigDecimal` to avoid the precision problem you can have with `double` or `float`.

Input:

```
Agnes 56 82 95 100 68 52 Bufford 87 92 97 100 96 85 93 77 98 86 Julie 99 100 100 89 96 100 92 99 68 Alice 40 36 85 16 0 22 72 Bobby 100 98 92 86 88
```

Output:

```
Name:Agnes Average:76
Name:Bufford Average:91
Name:Julie Average:94
Name:Alice Average:39
Name:Bobby Average:93
```

Comment: out of all of the kind suggestions this was the one that helped me the most, thank you, what I didn't think of was using a second loop

Answer (score 2):

This code will loop through as many times as you need. It will first read the name in, then constantly read numbers until another name is seen.

```
String next = scan.next();
while(scan.hasNext()) {
    String name = next;
    next = scan.next();
    int total = 0;
    int count = 1;
    while(!next.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$")) {
        total += Integer.parseInt(next)
        count++
        next = scan.next();
    }
    int average = total/count;
    System.out.println("Name: "+name+" Average: "+average);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

``Two or more, use a for'', Dijkstra said:

```
int numberOfScoresPerStudent = 10;

while(scan.hasNext()) {
     String name = scan.next();
     int sum = 0x00;
     while(scan.hasNextInt()) {
        sum += scan.nextInt();
     }
     int average = sum/ numberOfScoresPerStudent;
     System.out.println("Name:" + name + " Average:" + average);
}
```

Furthermore it is advisable to modify the computation of the average to:

```
double average = sum/ (double) numberOfScoresPerStudent;
```

Otherwise `6+5` will yield `5` as average.

Comment: the 10 has nothing to do with it, it was just the largest number of scores given to a student, the rest of the students has less. This is the list of names.                 Agnes 56 82 95 100 68 52
Bufford 87 92 97 100 96 85 93 77 98 86 
Julie 99 100 100 89 96 100 92 99 68
Alice 40 36 85 16 0 22 72
Bobby 100 98 92 86 88

Comment: Well you can set the `numberOfScoresPerStudent` parameter accordingly.

Comment: @FpRoT you should update the question with that data so that others could provide relevant answer.